# C Array char - When I try to write position 0, the program writes the position 0 and 1

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm writing a program and I need to store one character on a `char` array.

My problem is when I try to write the char array, the `postion[0]` prints the `postion[0]` + `position[1]` + `position[2]`, and I only want to get the character at `position[0]`.

Here is a program that I wrote just to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char position[3] = { '\0', '\0', '\0'};

    int Number;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf_s("\n\nNumber-> ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf_s("%d", &Number);

        position[Number - 1] = 'O';
    }

    printf("\n\n%s", &position[0]);
    printf("\n\n%s", &position[1]);
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n\n", &position[2]);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Program output]

What was my mistake?

Comment: Use `%c` instead of `%s`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, don't do it.

Comment: ...or, to augment comment of @SouravGhosh, if you do use `fflush(stdin)`, specify that you are using a platform (or C standard library), which defines what it does when you do that. If you aren't sure, don't use it.

Comment: `printf("\n\n%s", &position[0]);`-> `printf("\n\n%c", position[0]);`. Similar for the two other lines

Comment: Why are you using & to print data? and use %c to print character.

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: I expect to receive a message like:
O
O
O
And when I use %c instead of %s I get a printf like:
$
%
&

Comment: There is a major flaw in your code, if `Number` is too large you end up having a buffer overflow which would in turn cause undefined behavior. You can't predict the output of the program if it has the potential of undefined behavior.

Comment: I know @iharob, this is just a simple program that I create to solve the problem

Comment: @iharob The **potential** possibility to encounter UB is **not** the same as having UB in program. It is perfectly defined and predictable, as long as the **actual** input doesn't meet the conditions for UB.

Comment: @grek40 That doesn't mean that a programmer shouldn't care about it.

Comment: @iharob I never said that a programmer shouldn't care about UB, but a programmer should care about precise language and *"You can't predict the output of the program if it has the potential of undefined behavior"* is wrong.

Comment: @grek40 It's not wrong unless you have access to the source code and know that you can't type `xasdad` or `3` when the program asks you for input. Also, you might accidentally type something that would trigger the *undefined behavior* and then the program would have undefined behavior, since the behavior is only defined in terms of correct input for me the program HAS UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR ANYWAY!

Comment: @TelmoFerreira didn't my previous comment resolve the question ? Read it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are not just printing that `char` but the whole "*string*", for example

```
printf("%s\n", &position[0]);
```

is exactly the same as

```
printf("%s\n", position);
```

Then,

```
printf("%s\n", &position[1]);
```

is equivalent to printing the string starting at the second character instead of the first.

But that's not a real problem in your code, a real problem is that when `Number == 3` you have no `null` terminator, leading to undefined behavior in any of the `printf()`s no matter whether they are intended or a mistake from your lack of understanding how `printf()` works and what each specifier does, you MUST read documentation carefully before using any function.

To fix the problem, you can simply print the actual character. For that you have to use the `%c` specifier instead of `%s`, like this

```
printf("%c\n", position[1]);
```

would print the second element of the array.

Other issues with your code that I recommend you to fix are

1. Check the value of `Number` before trying to access the array, if it's big enough you could end up having inexplicable behavior, or it might be negative which would also be a problem.
2. Check the return value of `scanf_s()` to ensure that you did receive valid input from the user.
3. Do not use `\n` at the beginning of a line as it's awkward and most programmers don't do it unless it's really necessary.
4. Do not use `system("pause")` as it's simply a non standard way to deal with IDEs that probably expect a GUI program with an event loop instead of a command line program with text output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already program C# for two years and I know that the program has some problems. I created this program only to find out the problem , because the program I am doing has a lot more code.I'm learning C now, so that's why I made this simple mistake. Thank you

Comment: Very thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To print out a single char like `position[0]`, use this:

```
printf("\n\n%c", position[0]);
```

instead of:

```
printf("\n\n%s", &position[0]);
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that the problem has been solved so easily. I'm learning C and I always thought that I needed & before the variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! You only need '&' if you are getting the _address_ of the variable, which is the case in `scanf`. In `printf` you generally don't need it unless you want to print out the address of the variable

Comment: @TelmoFerreira please read my answer, for completion. You should accept this answer because it appeared first.

Comment: @iharob IMO an answer shouldn't be accepted because it's the first answer but because it's the best answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's essentially the same as my answer, so there is only clarification in mine that is absent here.

Comment: Accept @iharob's answer, it explains it a lot clearer